# OneToMany column not updating on creating enteries

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two entities/tables

Removed some columns for brevity

**Group:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups", indexes = {@Index(name = "groups_index", columnList = "id", unique = true)})
public class Group implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = UserInGroup.class, mappedBy = "group")
    private Set<UserInGroup> userInGroups = new HashSet<>();

}
```

**UserInGroup:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_in_group", indexes = {@Index(name = "user_in_group_index", columnList = "group_id,user_id", unique = true)})
public class UserInGroup implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Group group;

}
```

I have referred to these links [1](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52417245/4804250) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47070885/4804250). 
I have done what they have outlined

Now I make an entry in the **UserInGroup** table, and still, the **group** entity doesn't get updated with the new entries made in **UserInGroup** table.

[image: Creating entry in **UserInGroup**]

Group is not updated

[image: UserInGroups is still empty]

Entry Created in UserInGroups
[image: Entry Created in UserInGroups]

Entry created in Groups

[image: Entry created in Groups]

---

Edit:

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057400/4804250) I added the following

```java
UserInGroup userInGroup = new UserInGroup().setGroup(group).setUser(creatorUser).setGroupRoleEnum(GroupRoleEnum.ADMIN);
group.addUserInGroup(userInGroup);
groupRepository.save(group);
```

```java
public void addUserInGroup(UserInGroup userInGroup) {
    if (userInGroups == null) {
        userInGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    userInGroups.add(userInGroup);
    userInGroup.setGroup(this);
}
```

But the table **UserInGroup** still has no entries created.

Answer (score 0):

Well in your code, in your bi-directional relationship , you marked the `Group` entity as the owning side of the relation using the `mappedBy` attribute. So, if you use the `GroupRepository` instance to propagate both `Group` as well as the  `UserInGroup` values, everything should workout fine.That is instead of calling save on `UserInGroupRepository` instance use the `GroupRepository` instance to save the values and the foreign key association should be created automatically. Use `addUserInGroup(userInGroup)` and `removeUserInGroup()` methods to add or remove values to the set in Group class.

```
groupRepository.save(group);
```

Related post for more information : [Springboot add problem in oneTOMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014172/springboot-add-problem-in-onetomany-relation/62014249#62014249)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested. But the `groupRepository` doesn't save the `UserInGroup` entity.